# unsetting the WindowStaysOnTopHint makes window disappear

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a QWebView object and I set the *WindowStaysOnTopHint*, but when I turn it off, the QWebView object disappears.

```
view = QWebView()
view.setWindowFlags(WindowStaysOnTopHint)
view.show()
....
#in some slot
view.setWindowFlags(WindowStaysBottomHint)  # causes window to disappear
```

**UPDATE**

The previous setup was a simplified version of code, here are more details.

```
class Window(QObject):
    self.view = QWebView()
    self.view.setWindowFlags(WindowStayOnTopHint)
    self.installEventFilter(this)
....
    def eventFilter(self,qobject, qevent):
        if qevent.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
        # Turn on CloseButtonHint and turn off StayOnTopHint
        self.view.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        qobject.show()  # previously I had self.view.show(), does not cause window to show
    return super(FeedbackWindow, self).eventFilter(qobject, qevent)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for [setWindowFlags](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a
>   window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make
>   the widget visible again.